# How to turn off validation for specific project in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, validation

I have a project which structure I peek sometimes into for other projects. It has lots of errors which I don't care about. 
What I want is to turn off this annoying validation in Eclipse if possible, but only for this concrete project, at some point it drives really mad and defocuses me :-)

Thanks,

Comment: You can close that project, and open it when necessary.

Comment: That doesn't solve my problem when it is opened and I look at it.

Comment: What kind of errors do you mean? Java compiler errors, checkstyle, PMD, findbugs errors, ...? Depending on that, the solution may be different. And where do you see the errors: in the problems view, in the navigation tree (project explorer), in the text editors?

Comment: navigation tree + text editors I guess from your list that would java compiler errors.

Comment: If you want to turn java compiler off, just unchecked Project > Build Automatically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Project -> Clean,  then deselect the projects you're not interested in.  This also solves the case when you fix a problem, but the annotation for it still remains.

Answer (score 2):

You can't remove the errors annotations at a project level, you can remove or change its behaviour in the general settings going in : `Preferences -> Editors -> Text Editors -> Annotations -> Errors` and remove the checkbox on the three checkbox :

- Vertical Ruler
- Overview Ruler
- Text As

These configuration parameters are saved at workspace level, so you can have different configuration among different workspaces. So you can switch configuration switching workspace ...