# Turn off list expansion {*} error in eclipse DLTK for TCL

Tags: eclipse, tcl, dltk

We have some code that involves list expansion. When I use eclipse with the DLTK plugin I get the list expansions marked as error. Does anyone know a way to turn this off other than turning off error annotation completely like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8103340/12243443)?

[image]

Comment: The problem is that the DLTK plugin has an out-of-date grammar.

Comment: This has been reported to the DLTK project back in [2010](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/199606/), and they never addressed it.